# How do I implement a navbar that is stable when navigating pages?

Tags: styling, navbar

How can I make a navbar stable like on Twitter or Facebook? On those sites, the navbar doesn't even flinch. It is always visible, and only the page content changes? How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `position: fixed` property so that the navbar is always positioned relative to the  browser window instead of the content.

Comment: Navbar still flinches when going from one profile to another.
I would like it to always be stable and not flinch or anything